# How I can mock a class marked as final?

Tags: c++, testing, design-patterns, dependency-injection, software-design

## The problem

I need to add unit tests to the class `SensorClient` that contains a pointer to the object of the class `VelocitySensor` marked as final.

And what's important is that I can't modify the `VelocitySensor` class. Therefore, I can't change `VelocitySensor` methods to virtual... Also, I would like to avoid any "friend" classes or tricks with `#define`.

The code for the `VelocitySensor` class:

```cpp
//sensor_service.hpp
#pragma once
#include <string>

namespace sensor
{
    class VelocitySensor final
    {
    public:
        VelocitySensor() : velocity(20), sensorName("VelocitySensor") {}

        double getVelocity() const
        {
            return velocity;
        }

        std::string getSensorName() const
        {
            return sensorName;
        }

        void calculateSomething()
        {
            const double time = 10;
            auto vel = getVelocity();
            auto distance = vel * time;
            //...
        }
    private:
        std::string sensorName;
        double velocity;
    };
}
```

The code for the `SensorClient` class:

```cpp
//sensor_client.hpp
#pragma once
#include "sensor_service.hpp"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace sensor
{
    class SensorClient
    {
    public:
        SensorClient() : sensor(std::make_unique<VelocitySensor>()) {}

        double getVelocity() const
        {
            return sensor->getVelocity();
        }

        void calculateNumOfTyres()
        {
            sensor->calculateSomething();
        }

        std::string getVehicleName() const
        {
            return sensor->getSensorName();
        }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<VelocitySensor> sensor;
    };
};
```

## My solutions

I found three ways to solve that issue. Maybe there is another better solution ( I hope so :) )

### 1. Templatize `SensorCLient`

And as a result, it should be quite easy to mock `VelocitySensor` during tests.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "sensor_service.hpp"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>


namespace sensor
{
    template <typename T>
    class SensorClientTemplate
    {
    public:
        SensorClientTemplate(std::unique_ptr<T> _sensor = std::make_unique<VelocitySensor>())
            : sensor(std::move(_sensor)) {}
        virtual ~SensorClientTemplate() = default;

        double getVelocity() const
        {
            return sensor->getVelocity();
        }

        void calculateSomething()
        {
            sensor->calculateSomething();
        }

        std::string getSensorName() const
        {
            return sensor->getSensorName();
        }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<T> sensor;
    };

    using SensorClient = SensorClientTemplate<SensorService>;
};
```

For me, it looks quite good. But maybe there is another solution that doesn't require the use of templates.

### 2. Use the Adapter Pattern.

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "sensor_service.hpp"
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

namespace sensor
{
    class ISensor
    {
    public:
        virtual ~ISensor() = default;

        virtual double getVelocity() const = 0;
        virtual std::string getSensorName() const = 0;
        virtual void calculateSomething() = 0;
    };

    class SensorAdapter : public ISensor
    {
    public:
        void calculateSomething() override
        {
            sensor.calculateSomething();
        }

        double getVelocity() const override
        {
            return sensor.getVelocity();
        }

        std::string getSensorName() const override
        {
            return sensor.getSensorName();
        }

    private:
        VelocitySensor sensor;
    };

    class SensorClient
    {
    public:
        SensorClient(std::unique_ptr<ISensor> _sensor = std::make_unique<SensorAdapter>())
            : sensor(std::move(_sensor)) {}
        virtual ~SensorClient() = default;

        double getVelocity() const
        {
            return sensor->getVelocity();
        }

        void calculateSomething()
        {
            sensor->calculateSomething();
        }

        std::string getSensorName() const
        {
            return sensor->getSensorName();
        }

    private:
        std::unique_ptr<ISensor> sensor;
    };
};
```

Now I have an issue with adding tests to the adapter class... I moved the issue with mocking `VelocitySensor` to a new class. I would like to take care of code coverage... So this is not a solution for me.

### 3. Pimpl

I think I can use the Pimpl idiom to hide implementation details (including a pointer to the `VelocityObject`) in the *cpp file*, and as a result, I should be able to mock the implementation (now I don't need to mock `VelocitySensor`). But in that case, the implementation won't be covered by unit tests :(.
I found something about using factories to solve that issue, but I'm not sure how I can use that in my case,

**1 EDIT 2-05-2023**
Regarding proxy and my issue, Thanks @Pepijn Kramer, I think I understood. I have two options: a template or a proxy.

In order to prevent strong coupling between `VelocitySensor` and `SensorClient`, I need to define a proxy class. The proxy is strongly coupled to `VelocitySensor`, but `SensorClient`, which uses this proxy, is strongly coupled only to the interface implemented by the proxy. To add unit tests to the `SensorClient`, I need to mock all dependencies, and this assumes that the `SensorClient` should be loosely coupled to its dependencies. By proxy, this is not the case, so we can't write unit tests for proxy, but we can add integration tests to it.
Now, I can add tests to the `SensorClient` and mock proxy of the `VelocitySensor` :).

I assumed that if I want to achieve *100% code coverage*, I need to add UTs to everything (including the proxy, adapter, etc.). 
As I understand, sometimes it is impossible.

Comment: You can by deriving VelocitySensor from an abstract baseclass first and then make a mock for that abstract baseclass. Also with dependency injection constructors should not create the objects the want to "talk to", they must be injected too. E.g. SensorClientTemplate should not create the unique_ptr to SensorService

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't modify VelocitySensor. I am trying to figure out how to mock this class without modifying it. Regarding the creation of objects that want to "talk to", I thought that I could just set a default value... (Because it doesn't change anything - I can still inject mock class of VelocitySensor). Could you explain why I can't do that? Is it one of the "good practises"?

Comment: Which classes can you modify and which classes not. You can always make a proxy class for the VelocitySensor which has an abstract base and use that in the code you can modify. By starting with default behavior your class becomes dependent on the full declaration of the implementation class, by using strict dependency injection your class is only dependent on the interface (abstract base) and your design/source code will be more decoupled. (I hope this makes enough sense to you if not just ask again)

Comment: Regarding "dependency injection constructors should not create the objects", now I understand that I should avoid that because it can influence build time. It makes a coupling between SensorClientTemplate and VelocitySensor.

Comment: "Which classes can you modify and which classes not?" VelocitySensor can't be modified, but SensorClient can. Regarding proxy, I had to put my answer above. (It is too long for a comment.)